# как скачать файл с сайта используя firemonkey для android в delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

добавляю на форму только один webbrowser. при нажатии на ссылку ничего не происходит.
например, с этого сайта [по этой ссылке https://dle-news.ru/files/dle_trial.zip](https://dle-news.ru/demo.html)

Comment: пробовали http и https? Http обычно проще настроить.

Comment: доступа к сайту нет. протокол нет возможности поменять. задача: просматривать сайт и возможность скачивать файлы в телефон

Comment: Сначала пробуем настроить http скачивание, потом разбираемся с https. Не получается через web браузер, берем Indy.